# SQL Data only returned if filtering on inner select with ROW_NUMBER

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to get to the bottom of a query where there is only data returned if I filter on the inner select of the following statement:

Works:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT    
      [szPhoneNo] Email      
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CLID ORDER BY t_clientphone.PhoneType_Id ASC) AS Seq       
  FROM [SLacsis_SLM].[dbo].[T_ClientPhone] t_clientphone INNER JOIN 
  [SLacsis_SLM].[dbo].[TL_PhoneType] PT ON t_clientphone.PhoneType_ID = PT.PhoneType_ID  
  WHERE t_clientphone.szPhoneNo LIKE '%reg28%'          
            ) T where T.Seq = 1 --AND Email LIKE '%reg28%'
```

(10 rows returned)

Doesn't Work:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT    
      [szPhoneNo] Email      
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CLID ORDER BY t_clientphone.PhoneType_Id ASC) AS Seq       
  FROM [SLacsis_SLM].[dbo].[T_ClientPhone] t_clientphone INNER JOIN 
  [SLacsis_SLM].[dbo].[TL_PhoneType] PT ON t_clientphone.PhoneType_ID = PT.PhoneType_ID  
  --WHERE t_clientphone.szPhoneNo LIKE '%reg28%'            
            ) T where T.Seq = 1 AND Email LIKE '%reg28%'
```

(0 rows returned)

Can anyone explain why there are no rows returned for the second query and if there is a way that I can get around it?

I know that `ROW_NUMBER` is non-determistic when the `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` columns aren't unique (which is the case for a few of the rows in the inner select).

I'll see if I can recreate the issue using a temp table in the mean time.

Comment: It is because window functions are applied to records after all the records are known. In first case you are retrieving filtered records and get only matches, retrieving less rows than in a second. In second case Seq = 1 retrieves different records.

Comment: Thanks Nikola that makes sense to me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first items (ie: those where Seq=1) in the second query don't have an email like %REG28%.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow: There are records with Seq=1 and email like '%reg28%'. I'll post a sample of the nested select results in a sec.

Comment: @woggles Are you sure? What do you get if you the `AND Email like '%reg28%'` out of the second query?

Comment: I get the full result set in that case...but I see what Nikola is saying now. The row_number() will obviously be different when applied without the where clause in the inner select - resulting in a different record being ranked as 1. So you are right!